# how to take the value of a field of type "Name Value List" with a foreach?

Tags: c#, razor, sitecore

(on sitecore) I added a new field(named:Button) of type "Name Value List";
now, through a foreach, I should be able to take the value of the key which should become a button. All this will have to replace the previous code formed by each single "if" per button, namely this:

```
<div class="podcastsButtons__content">
             
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tit.Category.SprekerURL))
    {
        <button class='podcastsBtn podcastsBtn--spreaker' data-url='@tit.Category.SprekerURL'>
            <span></span>
        </button>
    }
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tit.Category.SpotifyURL))
    {
        <button class='podcastsBtn podcastsBtn--spotify' data-url='@tit.Category.SpotifyURL'>
            <span></span>
        </button>
    }
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tit.Category.ApplePodcastURL))
    {
        <button class='podcastsBtn podcastsBtn--apple' data-url='@tit.Category.ApplePodcastURL'>
            <span></span>
        </button>
    }
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tit.Category.GooglePodcastURL))
    {
        <button class='podcastsBtn podcastsBtn--google' data-url='@tit.Category.GooglePodcastURL'>
            <span></span>
        </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of a "Name Value List" field in Sitecore is stored internally similar to a query string, i.e. in the raw format `key1=value1&key2=value2` etc.

You can manually parse the field value using for example `Sitecore.StringUtil.ParseNameValueCollection`, but a simpler way is typically to just cast the field like this:

```
var field = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.NameValueListField) item.Fields["Button"];
foreach (var key in field.NameValues.AllKeys)
{
  var value = field.NameValues[key];
  // do something with key and value
}
```

It's worth noting that Sitecore has some internal encoding issues, so all characters can't be represented properly in a "Name Value List" field without causing content corruption.

Comment: thank you very much, exhaustive! however, on item.Field ["Button"] it reports error on item. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: "item" in this case is the current item you're working on. Could be the page item or rendering item. Just replace it with whatever your local item variable is called.